# Why a call from C++ to python has more delay than that from python to C++?

Tags: python, c++, time, boost-python, latency

I am using Boost python, to embed python in C++, this works totally fine, I have no issues with the coding part, so I am only attaching a pseudo code. I was interested in knowing the latency of a call from python to C++ and from C++ to python. I bench-marked the same and found that the call from **C++ to python took 6 microseconds (approx)** whereas that from **python to C++(via passed object) took 3 microseconds approx**. I wanted to know the reason behind it, can someone point out? psudo code I used:

```
[plugin.py]
start = time.time();
helper.push_into_vector(i, start)
[helper.cpp]
void push_into_vector(int i, int64_t start_time) {
  clock_gettime(&end);
  latency = end - start_time;
  /* do the actual work */
}I
```

Similarly for the other way of calls.

```
[helper.cpp]
clock_gettime(&start);
plugin.fib(o.get(), 1, 50, start);
[plugin.py]
define fib:
  end = time.time();
  latency = end - start;
  #do the actual work
```

compile command :

```
g++-8 helper.cpp read.cpp interns.pb.cc -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lboost_filesystem -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lboost_system -ldl -I /usr/include/python2.7 -lpython2.7 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lboost_python-py27 -lprotobuf -lpthread
```

Comment: *I bench-marked the same* -- You didn't state what C++ compiler you're using, what compiler options you used to build the sample program, whether you are timing an unoptimized "debug" build or an optimized "release" build, etc.

Comment: you might not have any issues with the coding part, but it would probably help us understand what you're measuring and how you're measuring it.  without this detail it's difficult to know what's going on

Comment: Indeed you would expect more latency from Python -> C++. Why can't you simply live with this, assuming of course you have measured it in a decent way and have appropriate compiler optimisations set?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks for the response I have added the compile commands

Comment: @SamMason the code has a lot of redundant things that I think are not relevant, but for checking latency I did exactly what I showed in the pseudo code(used time and clock_gettime())

Comment: @Bathsheba I also expected the same, but the latency from C++ to python is more in this case for some reason. And its not about living with it ;), I am trying to get to know the reason ...

Comment: I don't see any optimization flags on that command-line.  Optimizations are usually `-O2` or `-O3`.

Comment: My guess would be the Python interpreter.  If you are in Python, the interpreter is active (including the interpreter's environment).  A lot of Python is calling C or C++ code anyway.  So there should not be much latency in Python->C++.  However, when starting in C++ the Python environment is not loaded.  The Python environment (a.k.a. interpreter) will probably not be loaded until the first Python call is made (or maybe when Python is initialized).  There may also be some extra environment checks or setup when calling from C++ to Python.  This is just my guess.